# Angular Translate UrlLoader not working with my JSON Response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I am working on an application which is having multi language translations. I tried using Angular Translate UrlLoader. I am returning values in JSON from my Api. My api returns all the keys and translations of languages.

My API response looks something like this:

```
{"1":{"en":{"en":"English", "fr":"French","da":"danish"}},
 "2":{"fr":{"en":"Anglais", "fr":"français","da":"danois"}},
 "3":{"fr":{"en":"Engelsk", "fr":"fransk","da":"dansk"}}}
```

And in my script

```
$translateProvider.useUrlLoader('path/to/my/endpoint');
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
```

Incase if my Api returns a single language translation(for example it contains only French translation), it is translating a particular language by default(i.e., French). I don't know what i am doing wrong. Is the problem with returning JSON format from api or my end point not correct? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Do you have any console errors? Your question doesn't state clear enough what isn't working.

Comment: @DanielHigueras No error in console. In response, i am getting something like `{"1":{"en":{"Error_msg":"Error msg,...}},"2",{"fr":{"Error_msg":"erreur msg",...}},"3",{"da":{"Error_msg":"Fejl msg",...}}}` It is not translating anything in the template. My doubt is that can we able to keep all the three languages translation in a single json file?